# Strange behavior of drawing image in java

Tags: java, drawimage

I am making an animation by drawing different images dozens of milliseconds after the former one. something like this:

```
 drawimage(image1,0,0,null);

 try {

   Thread.sleep(100);

 }catch(Exception e){//To do something

 }

 drawimage(image2,0,0,null);
```

But the first image doesn't show until the second one appear. That means they appear at the same time.

My question is why does this happen?

Comment: I think it would be best if you split this up into two questions

Comment: have you tried sleeping for a longer period of time? can you also try include an SOP statement in your catch block and see if it prints anything?

Comment: Have you tried to increase the time of the delay?

Comment: Where exactly is this code? Is it in a `paint/paintComponent` method?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this. The images overlap. Are you trying to fade an image in?

Comment: I have tried a longer time, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @peeskillet it is in paintComponent. I use it to make animation, but I am not sure it is a good way. Could you recommend me some ways? Thanks.

Comment: @ylun Yes, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Tony See my edit, as I think I have found the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Me:** Where exactly is this code? Is it in a paint/paintComponent method?
>
> **OP:** it is in paintComponent. I use it to make animation, but I am not sure it is a good way.

You're right it isn't a good way. **Don't ever** call `Thread.sleep` in the `paintComponent` method. I would avoid the `Thread.sleep` all together and use a `javax.swing.Timer`.  See more [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

See examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21871022/2587435) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21593458/2587435) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21534549/2587435) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21801845/2587435).

**You could...**

Use a `list` of `Images` and every iteration firing of the `Timer` event, add another `Image` to the `List<Image>` and call `repaint()`

**You could...**

Have an `MyImage` object class that has an `Image` field and a `boolean draw` field. In the Timer, loop through the `MyImage` objects and do something like

```
    for (MyImage image: images) {
        if (!image.isDraw()) {
            image.setDraw(true);
            break;
        }
    }
    repaint();
```

For the `MyImage` `List` just loop through them in the `paintComponent` method and call it `drawImage` method, that you create.

---

Run this exmaple, showing the first option

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class AnimateImages extends JPanel {
    private static final int IMAGE_ROWS = 10;
    private static final int IMAGE_COLS = 10;
    private static final int IMAGE_SIZE = 50;
    private static final int DIM_WIDTH = IMAGE_COLS * IMAGE_SIZE;
            
    private final List<MyImage> images;
    private Image image;
    private int currX = -IMAGE_SIZE;
    private int currY;
    
    public AnimateImages() {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://swoo.co.uk/content/images/icons/stackoverflow.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AnimateImages.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        images = createImages();
        
        Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (MyImage image : images) {
                    if (!image.isDraw()) {
                        image.setDraw(true);
                        break;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }
    
    private List<MyImage> createImages() {
        List<MyImage> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_ROWS * IMAGE_COLS; i++) {
            if (currX >= DIM_WIDTH) {
                currX = 0;
                currY += IMAGE_SIZE;
            } else {
                currX += IMAGE_SIZE;
            }
            list.add(new MyImage(image, currX, currY));
            
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (MyImage img : images) {
            img.draw(g);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_COLS, IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_ROWS);        
    }

    public class MyImage {

        Image image;
        int x, y;
        boolean draw = false;

        public MyImage(Image image, int x, int y) {
            this.image = image;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public void setDraw(boolean draw) {
            this.draw = draw;
        }

        public boolean isDraw() {
            return draw;
        }

        public void draw(Graphics g) {
            if (draw) {
                g.drawImage(image, x, y, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, AnimateImages.this);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new AnimateImages());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Very good answer. Could you point me to the use of `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()`?

Comment: @ylun it is to run the app on the Event Dispatch Thread, as should be done with all swing app. See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more detail

Answer (score 1):

The program, in its current state, draws two images at the same time because there are two `draw methods` in the `loop` (if you are indeed using a loop).

In order to solve this issue, you should use only a single draw method and leave the delay in the same place. However, in order to cycle through all of the different image variables (if you have them named as numbers 1,2,3,4...etc in an array) you can use a for loop to draw them:

```
for (int i = 0; i<  *however many images you have*; i++){
     drawimage(image[i],0,0,null);

     try {

       Thread.sleep(100);

     }catch(Exception e){//To do something

     }
}
```

**Edit**

You do not use delays inside the `paintComponent`. Since you are, that is what is likely causing the issues. Move the delay into the `main` method of your program.

Comment: Could explain why it doesn't work in paintComponent ?

Comment: You cannot have variable names that start with (or are exclusively) numbers. This loop would not work.

Comment: @Tony When you add a `sleep` in the paintComponent, you are blocking the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) which causes the ui to freeze.

Answer (score 0):

**Your answer**

You're getting this result because it is printing `image1`, waiting .1 seconds and then printing `image2`. Then it doesn't wait at all, the game is immediately updated and then prints `image1`. Your display time for `image2` is microscopic and you're likely only seeing `image1` as a result.

Furthermore, the images are never deleted or replaced and so you are constantly drawing images on top of each other which is causing a memory leak, and is likely the cause of you seeing both images.

**Considerations**

This is a handy little animation class that I got, and still use, from [this tutorial](http://www.kilobolt.com/day-8-animations.html). This class is pretty handy and you can add the animated sprites necessary for each animation.

With this class, when you do a `drawImage()` you can use `object.getImage()` to extract the current frame of the animation.

Just make sure that you're calling the animation's `update()` method in your game's main loop so that the animations are constantly being updated.

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Animation {

    private ArrayList frames;
    private int currentFrame;
    private long animTime;
    private long totalDuration;

    public Animation() {
        frames = new ArrayList();
        totalDuration = 0;

        synchronized (this) {
            animTime = 0;
            currentFrame = 0;
        }
    }

    public synchronized void addFrame(Image image, long duration) {
        totalDuration += duration;
        frames.add(new AnimFrame(image, totalDuration));
    }

    public synchronized void update(long elapsedTime) {
        if (frames.size() > 1) {
            animTime += elapsedTime;
            if (animTime >= totalDuration) {
                animTime = animTime % totalDuration;
                currentFrame = 0;
            }
            while (animTime > getFrame(currentFrame).endTime) {
                currentFrame++;
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized Image getImage() {
        if (frames.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return getFrame(currentFrame).image;
        }
    }

    private AnimFrame getFrame(int i) {
        return (AnimFrame) frames.get(i);
    }

    private class AnimFrame {

        Image image;
        long endTime;

        public AnimFrame(Image image, long endTime) {
            this.image = image;
            this.endTime = endTime;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the mystery but provide a solution. Thanks anymore.

Comment: @Tony The mystery is explained in the first bit. Your code is stopping on the first image.

Comment: Sorry @leigero but that explanation is actually wrong. The two images, `1` and `2` are drawn, one after the other but never get removed and thus the statement that the display time for `image2` is "short" is false. The real reason is in both mine and peeskillet's answers

Comment: @ylun This is true, but the images are drawn on top of each other, so `image2` would never be seen. But this does create a memory leak for sure.