# Why do I have to use setvisible() on my JFrame when I change components?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So for the sake of simplicity I set up a little test code just to figure out this problem. Basically I have a `JFrame` and I added 'this' to it (I just extended my main class from `JComponent` to save time). this component fills in a red background. Then I have it sleep for 2 seconds and then type this.

```
f.remove(this);
thing t = new thing();
f.add(t);
f.setVisible(true);
```

f being my `JFrame` object and 'thing' is just another class extending `JComponent` that paints a blue background..

when I comment out `setvisible()` it no longer changes to blue.. I've tried using t.setVisible(true) but it seems I have to make the frame visible again, not the component

does anyone know why I have to call that... or if there is another way to change components within a single frame?

Answer (score 2):

> "Basically I have a JFrame and I added 'this' to it (I just extended my main class from JComponent to save time). this component fills in a red background. Then I have it sleep for 2 seconds and then type this."

1. Don't *"sleep"* your program. Instead use a `java.swing.Timer` to perform repeated tasks on the GUI or for animation. See more at [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). You can see a bunch of `Timer` examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21871022/2587435) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21593458/2587435) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21534549/2587435) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21801845/2587435) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22123304/2587435)
2. Instead of trying to add and remove panels look into using a `CardLayout` which allows you to switch between views. It will help you avoid a lot of problems that come with with adding and removing `components/containers`. See more at [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). Also see a simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21460065/2587435).
3. To answer your main question, whenever you remove and add components from your frame, you need to `revalidate()` it. `setVisible()` takes care of that for you.

---

**Side Note**

- Seems like a lot adding an removing background panels) just to change the background. Why not just `setBackround()`? You can switch colors with the use of the `Timer`

Answer (score 0):

Calling setVisible(true) makes the frame appear onscreen. Sometimes you might see the show method used instead. The two usages are equivalent, but we use setVisible(true) for consistency's sake.

Comment: Oh ok so I have to update the content pane as well as the component inside of it